# Mistake in x86 shellcode

Tags: assembly, x86, shellcode

I want to write assembly code that should run the following c function:

```
execv("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", 0])
```

I therefore wrote the following assembly code:

```
start:
    call main
    db '/bin/sh',7
main:
    xor edx, edx
    mov eax, 11    
    pop ebx
    push edx
    push ebx
    mov ecx, esp
    int 0x80
```

But somehow this does not work at all.. What exactly is wrong with it? I think I messed up something with the zerobyte of the array, but nor sure though.

Comment: Yeah well `7` is definitely not `0`. Why do you think that would work?

Comment: I did not really check properly the db instruction.. Thought I should put the length there. Is everything else right?

Comment: Yes, if you put a `0` there it works. But note if you want to use at classical shellcode you are not allowed to have a zero byte in your code. The usual workaround is to create the zero at runtime.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to figure that out on my own ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the line with the string to:

```
db '/bin/sh', 0
```